# How to get data from pdf in Cyrillic?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have error when I try to get data in cyrillic

```
import codecs
pdfFileObj = codecs.open('1.pdf', 'rb','utf-8')
```

The error is

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 1):

### PDF is not a textfile

PDF is not unicode, PDF is full of binary streams, with text, images and so on.

### Use some PDF library

Take look at [PyPDF2](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2). To get text from first page do

```
pdf = PdfFileReader(open('/tmp/russian.pdf', 'rb'))
text = pdf.getPage(0).extractText()
```

Though you might also need to convert it to *windows-1251*

```
text.encode('latin').decode('windows-1251')
```

Comment: спасибо я пробовал но все таки не выводит кириллицу

Comment: @ЛесханКаратаев You'd have to show me that pdf. And please speak English.

Comment: can you give me youur e-mail.

Comment: @ЛесханКаратаев No…

Comment: Guys, any updates on this? I'm not sure it's able to "read" Cyrillic at all. `len(pdf.getPage(0).extractText())` — 0 symbols.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with [pdfminer.six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six); it supports cyrillic chars

```py
from pdfminer import high_level

with open('file.pdf', 'rb') as f:
    text = high_level.extract_text(f)
    print(text)
```

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70501572/3367753