# How to parse table in PDF for non-english language

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, pdf, python-camelot

I was using Camelot and tabula for parsing a pdf file with Cyrillic symbols inside. But in the output CSV file, I got the messed-up font with no sign of Russian language.

What can help me to parse the pdf table in a non-English language?

```
import camelot
file = 'file-name.pdf'
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages = "1-end", encoding='utf-8')
```

**Output:**
00550529-1295-06 -РўРљР 5.РЎРћ1 0520529-12955--0066--РўРўРљРљР Р 55--Р“Р“Р§Р§23  00552299--11229955--0066--РўРўРљРљР Р 55--Р“Р“Р§Р§45

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get data from pdf in Cyrillic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581122/how-to-get-data-from-pdf-in-cyrillic)

Comment: Please post an example of PDF

Comment: @mutantkeyboard the way that this guy showed doesn't work at all

Comment: @StefanoFiorucci-anakin87 I already got the answer. It allows to parse the page and convert it into pandas DataFrame which is fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically, Camelot is pretty good with Cyrillic.

```
pip install camelot-py[cv]
import pandas as pd
import camelot
file = 'file-name.pdf'
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages = "4, 5", encoding='utf-8')
df_p4 = tables[0].df
```

The output will be pretty raw, needs cleaning, but symbols won't be broken which I assume is a good result.