# How to search a set of pdfs, with only an image segment of a page

Tags: python, database, pdf

The main idea is this, I have a large collection of IGCSE past papers, I need to find which paper a particular question was from, and all I have is the screenshot of one question. I want to make a program that can input an image of a question, then scan a set of pdfs to find the said question, then output the pdf containing the said question. I have experience in programming but I'm a bit stuck into how to approach the problem at hand.

Solutions I have tried:

- I tried combining pdfs into one mega pdf so I could just search the mega pdf, can't do that as the file is too large.

Solutions I think might work but not sure:

- Making a program to read through every single pdf to find the keywords in the image.

Comment: Hi this is just an idea, but here goes I did a bit of a google and found this.
https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext
pdf to text
You could use that to get the text of the pdf page, then store that and then you can do a search. Maybe a bit hacky and old school not too sure how effective it would be.

Comment: Another idea, sharepoint has a good search and can do pdf's - upload your pdfs there and search away.

Comment: Here is a question which may assist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098675/searching-text-in-a-pdf-using-python

Comment: So a few options there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the steps in https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter13/ ? 
- put all pdf's in the same folder 
- for each pdf go through each page 
- perform extractText()
- use regex or something to parse this extractText for the questionstring then output pdf/page if found

Comment: Exactly the type of solution I was searching for.